# Зачем boost::asio::io_service помещать в отдельный поток?

Tags: c++, boost

Задался вопросом, а зачем в данном примере `io_service` в разных потоках...

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;

int main()
{
  io_service ioservice;

  steady_timer timer1{ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{3}};
  timer1.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
  { std::cout << "3 sec\n"; });

  steady_timer timer2{ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{3}};
  timer2.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
  { std::cout << "3 sec\n"; });

  std::thread thread1{[&ioservice](){ ioservice.run(); }};
  std::thread thread2{[&ioservice](){ ioservice.run(); }};
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();
}
```

Попробовал просто `io_service.run()` и один раз в главном потоке - и так же все асинхронно вывелось... в чем профит?

Answer (score 1):

Приципильно разницы нет, т.е. один из ioservice.run(); вы можете вызвать в отдельном потоке, а второй в главном. Но тогда вы блокируете главный поток. Если же оба ioservice.run(); вы вызываете в отдельных потоках, то в главном вы можете производить какую-то работу, а потом вставить на ожидание завершения.

Comment: хм, а io_service.run() разве блокирующая?

Comment: The run() function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the io_service has been stopped.

Comment: понял, спасибо... если так, то да, нужно в отдельном потоке вызывать